# Find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that both $\sum {a_n}$ and $\sum{\frac{1}{n^2 a_n}}$ converge.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that both $\sum_1^\infty {a_n}$ and
>   $\sum_1^\infty {\frac{1}{n^2 a_n}}$ converge. If no such sequence
>   exists, prove that.

Actually the question was  for $\sum_1^\infty  {n{a_n}}$ and $\sum_1^\infty {\frac{1}{n^2 a_n}}$. For this problem; If we suppose that both are convergent, then their multiply $\sum_1^\infty  1/n$ must be convergent and this is a contradiction.

But for $\sum_1^\infty  {a_n}$ and $\sum_1^\infty {\frac{1}{n^2 a_n}}$, if we multiply  we get $\sum_1^\infty  1/n^2$ which is convergent. I tried to find a sequence such that both the series converge but I couldn't find any but also I couldn't prove that there is no such sequence exists.

Edit. $a_n >0$

Comment: I think that $a_n>0$ should be a condition to make the question really interesting

Comment: @ajotatxe yes. The book I found the first question, said at the first of the series chapter, that for all questions, consider $a_n>0$ and I forgot to mention that.

Comment: With the condition $a_n > 0$ it is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1933001/42969.

Comment: If $a_n>0$, by Cauchy-Schwarz $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2 a_n}\geq H_N^2\geq \log^2(N).$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes, an example is
$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$
However, there is no such a sequence with positive terms.
Indeed, if you suppsose that both $\sum a_n$ and $\sum\frac{1}{n^2a_n}$ are convergent and with positive terms, then you have by the AM-GM inequality
$$\sum \frac{1}{n}=\sum \sqrt{a_n \cdot \frac{1}{n^2a_n}} \le \sum \frac{1}{2}  \left(a_n + \frac{1}{n^2a_n} \right) < +\infty$$
which implies that the harmonic series is convergent: a contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a bit too trivial?

$a_n=(-1)^n(1/n)$

Answer (score 6):

The above answer shows that if the $a_n$s are allowed to change sign, then the sum may converge. However, if the $a_n$s are all positive, then by the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchysInequality.html),

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n}&=\sum_{n= 1}^k\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{\sqrt{n^2a_n}}\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{n =1}^ka_n\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n= 1}^k\frac{1}{n^2a_n}\right)^{1/2}
\end{align*}

Since $\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n}\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$, one of $\sum a_n$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n^2a_n}$ must diverge.